# How to silence print statements in for Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I have code like so:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options, )
browser.get(url)
```

This prints a lot of output from selenium. I was wondering if there is a way to silence that?

Solutions like this:

```
sys.stdout = None
sys.stderr = None
```

do not work.

Comment: What is the sense of having a func which prints something, if printed content would be deleted?

Comment: If you don't want things to be printed, why is the code to print output there in the first place? How would you solve the problem if the code *weren't* threaded? Is the question really "how can `func` detect which thread is running?"? If not, then what is the actual difficulty?

Comment: I recommend using logging, it is then easy to regulate the level of verbosity

Comment: It is moreso that I want output of this function to be printed when it is called once but not when it is called 1000 times through threading. I have some updated information and will edit question shortly.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about any output, you could simply modify `sys.stdout`:

```
import sys
stdout_ref = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = None
print('this won\'t be visible!')

threads = []
for _ in range(n):
    th = Thread(target = func)
    threads.append(th)
    th.start()
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

# Reset stdout
sys.stdout = stdout_ref
print('working again!)
```